# Rendering Some Alpha Rectangles is Glitchy on Some Computers

Tags: java, rendering, lighting

I've been working on a game in Java, and recently I decided to try out my game on a netbook just to see how it would run. While I do get a constant 60 FPS, it appears that my lighting rendering decides to freak out a bit. This only happens on the netbook, however, and I'm not sure how I can fix it.

Here's the lighting glitch:

[image]

As you can see, for some reason there are sometimes vertical and (although not shown) horizontal lines that the alpha rectangles apparently aren't drawing over.

I'm using Graphics to draw on a JFrame, and the block rendering code looks like this:

```
g.drawImage(sprite, (int)x, (int)y, null);
g.setColor(new Color(0,0,0,<insert darkness level>));
g.fillRect((int)x,(int)y,32,32);
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the code itself, which is why I'm not sure how to fix this. If someone could help, I'd be really grateful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If it's the code to draw one block, can you provide the loop to draw all blocks?

Comment: I used a simple for loop.

for(int i=0;i<blocks.size();i++)
blocks.get(i).render(g);

Comment: Can you provide the values of `x`s and `y`s?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Blocks are snapped to a 32x32 grid on creation, if that helps.

Comment: I should also mention that: The lines flicker on and off as I move around, and placing two blocks on top of each other prevents the glitch for those blocks.

Comment: I would like to know the output of `for(int i=0;i<blocks.size();i++) System.out.println(blocks.get(i).getX() + " " + blocks.get(i).getY());` or something similar when the glitch occur.

Comment: Sorry, Stack wasn't letting me post comments. :/ Here are the block xs/ys http://pastebin.com/1uJyAP8B

Comment: I thought there might be some misaligned blocks due to round-off errors, but seems like it's not the case. But I still want to check if using `round()` change anything.

Comment: Sorry, even using x=Math.round(x) and y=Math.round(y) every tick doesn't make any difference. :/